# http://localhost:7474/db/data/ returns a 404 after login

Tags: neo4j

I've installed the latest version of Neo4J Desktop and started the Movie Database

I'm in a VirtualBox VM running Windows 10 and the Firewall is disabled.

IN Chrome inside the VM running Neo4J ....

http://localhost:7474/ redirects to http://localhost:7474/browser/ and works (https urls return SSL errors)

However http://localhost:7474/db/data/ prompts me for credentials and after submitting the user/pwd displays a 404  error.

So 2 questions

1.) How can I get to http://localhost:7474/db/data/ in my browser?

2.) How can I get rid of the SSL errors ?

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Neo4j REST API](https://neo4j.com/docs/rest-docs/current/) is no longer supported (since neo4j 4.0). If you want to use HTTP requests to perform Cypher transactions, you can look at the [Neo4j HTTP API](https://neo4j.com/docs/http-api/current/).

SSL support is not enabled by default. Instructions for setting that up are [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/security/ssl-framework/).